# How to ignore a property change notification in angular form?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm new to Angular and my question may sound strange because of my winform/wpf background...I use $scope.$pristine to check if the model data is modified by user. However, on this form, there is a checkbox (e.g. Close when Save button is clicked) which should be excluded, that is, if it is checked or unchecked, it should not make the scope dirty. So, how to exclude it from the change notification loop of angular? Or there is a completely different way to do it?

Comment: Organize your markup so that the checkbox is outside of the form?

Comment: Well, it works for some cases, but it will be difficult for other cases.

Answer (score 0):

I would put the "close when saved" check box outside of the form you can still access $scope.closeWhenSaved if it's within the html boundaries of the from you will need to look into using [ngForm](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angForm) nesting